# controllerWillChangeContent not being called when deleting all entries of an entity

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, delete-row

Below is the method I have implemented for a tableView "reset" button.  I've verified that the entries in the Entity are being deleted, however my controllerWillChangeContent is not being called after the deletion.  Is there a way to call this method manually?

```
CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [[CoreDataStack alloc]init];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"FoodEntry"];
[fetchRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [coreDataStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *object in fetchedObjects)
{
    [coreDataStack.managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];
}

error = nil;
[coreDataStack.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

**EDIT : FRC CODE**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: I suspect your delete code is using a different managedObjectContext from your fetched results controller.  Please can you show the code for the FRC.

Comment: Also, when is this code run, and what fetch request is the table view using

Comment: Your are correct it is not linked with my FRC just not sure how to fix this, still new to coding.  It's called when the user pushes a "reset" button.  The entires are being deleted, I just need the table view to update appropriately when pressed.  Above is my FRC code under "EDIT".  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be certain, without knowing the internals of `CoreDataStack`, but it looks like you are using two different stacks: notice that your code uses:

```
CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [[CoreDataStack alloc] init];
```

whereas the FRC uses:

```
CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
```

You could change your code to use the same as the FRC (`defaultStack` is probably a singleton and will return the same stack whenever it is called).  But if the FRC is in the same class as the delete code, it will be easier (and clearer) to just use the FRC's managedObjectContext:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"FoodEntry"];
[fetchRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *object in fetchedObjects)
{
    [context deleteObject:object];
}
error = nil;
[context save:&error];
```

Incidentally, it's always worth checking if the `executeFetchRequest:` and `save:` return an error.

Comment: ah! yea thats right I have my coreDataStack setup in its own class file as a singleton.  Changing it to [coreDataStack defaultStack] fixed it. thanks a ton!